# Dynamic Loading of third drop down in jQuery ajax in the WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I Need to create the dynamic drop down of category in the WordPress. Is their any plugin in WordPress for the category drop down?

Eg: cars is the Category,
      BMW is the sub category of the cars and
      7 series is the sub of sub category .

Here How to display the parent category in the First drop down.and related sub category of the parent category in the Second drop down.

And if the Sub category has the Sub of Sub category means third drop down should display, If not third drop down should not display.

Is their any plugin for this scenario in the WordPress

Answer (score 0):

may be that's the plugin that you were looking for.

```
http://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-vertical-mega-menu/screenshots/
```

Try it..
here is the list..
http://www.wpstand.com/wordpress/plugins/14-free-wordpress-menu-plugins.html

Comment: ,this plugin for menu which displaying in vertical slides, Actually I need to display as drop down in search.

Comment: I've found these links may be this would help u.
http://www.designchemical.com/lab/demo-wordpress-vertical-accordion-menu-plugin/#
2nd Link:
http://perishablepress.com/jquery-accordion-menu-tutorial/#
more menus ..
http://streetsmash.com/jquery-accordion-menu/